# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS login manager

Tags: 14.04, login, kdm, mdm

So here is the problem that I am having. I came back to Ubuntu from Manjaro linux and enjoy the beautiful design. I was always a fan of the login screen/manager for Ubuntu. It was very sleek looking but I'm not sure what the official name of it was/is. With the new install of 14.04 I have noticed that all I get at the login screen is my username to login and a boring gray and noisy background. I don't recognize this login manager but everything is centered and kinda boring. How do I get back to the original, fancy Ubuntu login manager? Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a picture of that screen? The login manager is called LightDM and is still used in 14.04, so it may be some problem with your setup.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are using Ubuntu GNOME, which uses GDM as the [Display Manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager), as it is usually called. What you are looking for is LightDM, the default display manager of Ubuntu. You can install it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm unity-greeter
```

Choose `lightdm` as the default when you are asked:
[image: dpkg-reconfigure screenshot]

You can always change your default by using the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

(Or use any other DM you may have installed, in place of `lightdm`.)

Answer (score 0):

The Display Manager with the icons on the left is `gdm` I believe.  `lightdm` has a more windows-like toolbar in my opinion.  Another test when pressing **super** (windows button):
`gdm`:  get the search bar all along the top of the screen, with lots of icons below it.
`lightdm`:  pops up a shortcut bar on the left, search on top, workstations on right and open windows in center.