# How do I use lightdm for login instead of light-locker?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lightdm, xfce, light-locker

I installed xubuntu on my laptop and recently removed nearly all of the xfce4 packages in favor of a kde desktop. However, light-locker is still used for the login screen. How can i remove it and enable the standard lightdm login screen of kde?

Comment: Mostly asking this out of curiosity, but if you wanted KDE, why not opt for the KDE spin of Ubuntu, [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) instead of removing all the XFCE4 packages? You'd have an easier time backing up your Home directory and installing Kubuntu that way. :)

Comment: The steps in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/504698/158442) should suffice.

Comment: Note that there is also KDM (as an alternative to `lightdm`).